# iOS: Returning an object from a callback

Tags: ios, callback, return, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have three functions. Please note that these are pseudocode:

1. callService, which takes 2 arguments, and returns URLSessionDataTask
2. validateService, which takes a closure, and doesn't return anything
3. runService, which takes 3 arguments, and returns URLSessionDataTask

The function *validateService* will execute a validation service, after which *runService* will be called in the callback. That is, runService will be executed after the validation service is finished.

The function *callService* will call *validateService*. Once *runService* is finished executing, it will return URLSessionDataTask, which will be returned by *callService*.

Question: How can I possibly get the NSURLSessionDataTask from *runService* in *callService*? And which option is better to implement? Also is there another (easier/better) way that I have not thought of where I can get the NSURLSessionDataTask object from *runService* in my *callService*?

**Option 1: Using pass-by-reference**

Problem: This code fails because dataTask needs to be __autoreleasing, however when I add __autoreleasing, I get the error: *cannot capture __autoreleasing variable in a block*

```
//NOTE: THIS PART IS OBJ-C
(NSURLSessionDataTask *)callServicewithSuccess:(SuccessHandler)successBlock
                                         andFail:(FailHandler)errorBlock
{
   NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask;
   [WMTValidateUserService validateService:^{
                [self runServicewithSuccess: successBlock 
                                    andFail:errorBlock 
                                    andDataTask:&dataTask];

            } failBlock:^{
                [self runServicewithSuccess: successBlock 
                                    andFail:errorBlock 
                                    andDataTask:&dataTask];

            }];
    return dataTask;
}



- (void)runServicewithSuccess:(SuccessHandler)successBlock
                                     andFail:(FailHandler)errorBlock
                                     andDataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask**)dataTask
{
    *dataTask = someExpression;
}


//NOTE: THIS PART IS IN SWIFT
class func validateService(_ successBlock: @escaping () -> (), failBlock: @escaping () -> () )
{
    ServiceHandler.shared().getValidateUser(success: { _ -> Void in successBlock() },
                                            fail: { _ -> Void in failBlock() })
}
```

**Option 2: Using pass-by-value**

Problem: runService returns NSURLSessionDataTask, but the callback in callService does not allow me to get that object.

Question: How can I write validateService so that it returns NSURLSessionDataTask?

```
//NOTE: THIS PART IS OBJ-C
(NSURLSessionDataTask *)callServicewithSuccess:(SuccessHandler)successBlock
                                         andFail:(FailHandler)errorBlock
{
   NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask;
   [WMTValidateUserService validateService:^{
                [self runServicewithSuccess: successBlock 
                                    andFail:errorBlock 
                                    andDataTask:dataTask];

            } failBlock:^{
                [self runServicewithSuccess: successBlock 
                                    andFail:errorBlock 
                                    andDataTask:dataTask];

            }];
    return dataTask;
}



- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)runServicewithSuccess:(SuccessHandler)successBlock
                                     andFail:(FailHandler)errorBlock
                                     andDataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask*)dataTask
{
    dataTask = someExpression;
    return dataTask;
}


//NOTE: THIS PART IS IN SWIFT
class func validateService(_ successBlock: @escaping () -> (), failBlock: @escaping () -> () )
{
    ServiceHandler.shared().getValidateUser(success: { _ -> Void in successBlock() },
                                            fail: { _ -> Void in failBlock() })
}
```

Thank you